# Customizing & Styling Angular X-Editable Popover Input

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, x-editable

I'm using angular x-editable in my project for an [editable popover](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-popover). I've successfully made changes to the look of my confirmation button to an .svg I wanted to use and removed the Cancel button doing:

```
app.run(function(editableOptions, editableThemes) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'default';
  editableThemes[default].cancelTpl = '';
  editableThemes[default].submitTpl = '<img class="popoverSubmitBtn" 
    src="images/confirmationBtn.svg" ng-click="$form.$submit()">';
});
```

However I am having issues when trying to change   `editableThemes[default].inputTpl`. It seems like changes to `inputTpl` are not being registered for some reason. What I would like is for the input box that shows in the popover to have a circular 'x' button to clear the current input **WITHIN** the input text field.

This was actually default behavior in the original x-editable (see [here](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) at Twitter typeahead.js demo). While there is an equivalent to use `editableOptions.displayClearButton=true`, this creates an entire button next to the input box, much like the confirmation button, which is not what I want.

My plan was to use a directive here that provides the 'clear' button and use `editableThemes[default].inputTpl = '<input type="text" reset-directive>';` but again, seems like its broken. Even this open issue [here](https://github.com/vitalets/angular-xeditable/issues/223) leads me to believe it was never working as intended.

Has anyone had any luck with this or knows of any workarounds that may help in my situation?

ALSO- a bit unrelated but on the topic of styling, how do I move the position of where the popover shows up? Currently it's smack-dab in the middle of where my cursor is when I click the text to activate popover, but I would like it a bit higher and to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. For those with similar issues:

- Styling for the popover can be controlled through `xeditable.css` found in the `bower_components` directory after installation
- While `inputTpl` isn't functioning the way I expected, I added the
  custom directive to the input field using `e-*` (i.e. `e-my-directive`) with no issues.